# Remove Password from an Excel File which i know the passwords

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have a problem in using VBA to remove normal password use to enter into a password protected Excel and also the modification passwords.

I have the password available. ie "1234" is the password to load the Excel and "abcd" is the one to allow user to modify the content.

I wanted to create an Excel app that can automatically remove the passwords that I stored in 1 or few.
Excel file (Xlsx and Xls format (old)).

The scenario is

a) I have my password "1234" (for opening the excel) and "abcd" for (modifying the Excel).

b) After I entered both the password (Normal & Modify) onto the Excel file, I would like to programmatically using VBA to remove both the passwords which I have ("1234" and "abcd").